# How can I fix or understand why my static files dont process by express.static

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static-files

I write some routing on Express js and i have 2 routers here. There are /posts and /posts/:id . And when I try to get result by ID I have an error : my static file app.css was not processed by express.static() and come to req.url , due to it my code doesn't work and give me undefined. So pug view renders , but thus it is cant get css

There is my main file : server.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('index')
})
app.use('/posts', require('./routes/posts.js'))


app.listen(3000)
```

This is my posts.js Router

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = express.Router();
const posts = require('../data/posts.json');


router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('posts', {
        posts: posts
    })
});
router.get('/:id', (req ,res)=>{
    console.log(req.url);
    const post = posts.find(post=> post.id == req.params.id);
    console.log(post);
    res.render('post', {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

Here is an error and results of logs

```
/2
{ title: 'Посадка помидоров',
  content: 'Как я посадила помидоры и они не выросли',
  id: 2 }
/app.css
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

Comment: Confusing question.  Your title asks about a problem with `express.static()`, but the text of your question seems to show some sort of problem with `res.render()`.  To actually help you with an `express.static()` question, we need to see your file structure, see the `express.static()` code and see the actual href in the HTML page that is supposed to be served by `express.static()` so we can figure out what exact URL is being requested from your server and whether that matches your `express.static()` configuration and your file system.

Comment: The typeerror has nothing to do with css. It comes from your `/:id` route and tell you that you forgot to make sure that `post = ...` _actually yields a post. It doesn't. The result of `find()` is undefined.

Comment: There is a problem with attribute href in link tag in Pug views. Thanks for your precept. It was just app.css, but when I changed it to absolute path '../public/app.css' it has worked .